# Corresponding files are not installed correctly when compiling the Gnuradio OOT module

Tags: linux, cmake, makefile, compiler-errors, gnuradio

I followed the [official tutorial](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=Creating_Python_OOT_with_gr-modtool) to create an OOT module.

Specifically, I created module with `gr_modtool newmod customModule` and then add a block named addSubSelect by `gr_modtool add addSubSelect`

After editing the corresponding py and yml files, I created "build" folder and executed `cmake ..` `make` `sudo make install` in turn.

The output of `sudo make install` is:

````
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/gnuradio-customModule/gnuradio-customModuleConfig.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gnuradio/customModule/api.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml/index.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml/compound.xsd
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml/index.xsd
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml/api_8h.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml/indexpage.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml/main__page_8dox.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml/dir_d44c64559bbebec7f509842c48db8b23.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml/group__block.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml/pydoc__macros_8h.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml/xml.xsd
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml/namespacestd.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml/combine.xslt
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml/dir_359d2bec989c9a8deeeb9aee335c1c76.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml/dir_91ae7363f720a5ef22927ff13906c8a2.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml/dir_f2cd86917185299abf5a1f0679072f3c.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml/dir_902d6fe55786be073ae6681293cdb979.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml/group__defs_8dox.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/xml/dir_49e56c817e5e54854c35e136979f97ca.xml
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/sync_off.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/dynsections.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/navtree.css
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/group__block.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/jquery.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/doxygen.svg
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/api_8h.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/doxygen.css
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/nav_h.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/folderopen.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/tab_h.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/tabs.css
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/files_dup.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/tab_a.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/pydoc__macros_8h.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/files.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/bc_s.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/globals.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/pydoc__macros_8h.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/dir_49e56c817e5e54854c35e136979f97ca.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/api_8h_source.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/bdwn.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/group__defs_8dox.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/splitbar.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/nav_f.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/globals_defs.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/navtreeindex0.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/dir_902d6fe55786be073ae6681293cdb979.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/main__page_8dox.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/doc.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/closed.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/dir_359d2bec989c9a8deeeb9aee335c1c76.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/modules.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/folderclosed.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/dir_91ae7363f720a5ef22927ff13906c8a2.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/resize.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/pydoc__macros_8h_source.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/tab_s.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/navtree.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/open.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/nav_g.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/dir_d44c64559bbebec7f509842c48db8b23.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/index.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/api_8h.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/navtreedata.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/tab_b.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/dir_f2cd86917185299abf5a1f0679072f3c.html
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/sync_on.png
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/doc/gr-customModule/html/modules.js
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gnuradio/customModule/__init__.py
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gnuradio/customModule/__init__.pyc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gnuradio/customModule/__init__.pyo
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/customModule_addSubSelect.block.yml```
````

However, according to the tutorial, the correct output should be

```
[  0%] Built target pygen_apps_9a6dd
[  0%] Built target copy_module_for_tests
[100%] Built target pygen_python_customModule_f524f
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/gnuradio-customModule/gnuradio-customModuleConfig.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/gnuradio/customModule/api.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/gnuradio/customModule/__init__.py
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/gnuradio/customModule/addSubSelect.py
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/gnuradio/customModule/__init__.pyc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/gnuradio/customModule/addSubSelect.pyc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/gnuradio/customModule/__init__.pyo
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/gnuradio/customModule/addSubSelect.pyo
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/customModule_addSubSelect.block.yml
```

It seems that only **init**.py was installed correctly in my output, consequently an error raised when I tried to run a flowgraph includes the OOT module:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gnuradio/customModule/init.py", line 23, in <module>
from .addSubSelect import addSubSelect
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gnuradio.customModule.addSubSelect'
```

Because there is no other .py files in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gnuradio/customModule/

I have added

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages:/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

to `~/.profile`
When I typed `gnuradio-config-info --prefix` its output is `/usr/local`

I copied the corresponding .py file to /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gnuradio/customModule/, and the module started working!

I'm wondering if it's possible to fix this bug and avoid copying the file manually every time.

Thank you!

Comment: Please, add to the question post the **exact steps** which you have performed while adding addSubSelect block to your project.